# upload button on selection of dropdown item in Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a select option and file upload control. The default value of dropdown is set to select. I have a file upload control, where on load the upload button should be disabled/hidden and when user selects an item other than select in dropdown the upload button should be enabled, and a custom message should be shown about the option selected in dropdown. I have tried the below, but seems to be an issue. In index.html

```
<body ng-controller="Main as vm">

     <div class="container">
                <br />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <label class="control-label">Select Environment :<em style="color:red">*</em></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                        <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" class="dropdown form-control cl-sm-6" ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions track by option.id" ng-model="data.selectedOption" ng-change="selectEnvironmentChanged()"  ></select>                       
                    </div>   
                    <label ng-show="vm.showWarning">Warning message</label>  
                    <label ng-show="vm.showEnvironmentMessage">You have selected </label>           
                </div>

         <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group" >
                        <label for="newfiles">Select and upload files</label>
                        <input type="file" id="imageUploadfile" class="uploadFile" accept="image/*" my-files="files" ngf-multiple="false" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-if="showBtns" ng-show="showUpload"  ng-click="uploadNewFiles()" value="upload" />
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

In the controller page, I have code as

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var myApp = angular.module('app',[]);

    myApp.controller('Main', function ($scope) {      

        $scope.showUpload = false;


        $scope.data = {
            availableOptions: [
              { id: '1', name: 'Select' },
              { id: '2', name: 'aY1' },
              { id: '3', name: 'aY3' },
              { id: '4', name: 'bA4' }

            ],
            selectedOption: { id: '1', name: 'Select' }
        };

        $scope.selectEnvironmentChanged = function () {
            if ($scope.data.selectedOption !== 'Select') {
                vm.showWarning = true;
                $scope.showUpload = true;
                vm.showEnvironmentMessage = true;
            } else {
                vm.showWarning = false;
                vm.showEnvironmentMessage = false;
                $scope.showUpload = false;
            }
        };
```

Currently onload of the page the upload button is hidden, but if I select any other item in dropdown the upload button is not showing. Also, I want to show in the "showEnvironmentMessage" as You have selected Option 1, if the user selects  ay1, if they choose ay2, then show message as you have selected option 2 in the "showEnvironmentMessage"label. 
How to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: You start by initializing `selectedOption` to an object with an ID and a name. And two lines later, you're comparing `selectedOption` with a string. That doesn't make much sense: an object will always be different from a string. Read the documentation of ng-options. Be consistent in your choices: either the selected value should be a string, or it should be an object, but it can't be both. You're also using a variable `vm` that you haven't defined anywhere. Be consistent, again. EIther you use the scope, or you use the controller. Don't mix both, and don't use something before understanding it

Comment: Thanks. Is this correct - if ($scope.data.selectedOption.id !== 1) {

Comment: No. Again, read your code, and be consistent. The IDs in your options are strings. And you compare id with the number 1. Take a big step backwards, read the documentation of ng-options, make some design to choose the types of your variables and fields, and stick to this design.